# Interbrowser tab transaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an inter-tab transaction following this scenario:

1. I have a page that has a `table` on it.
2. On this `table`, there are `rows`. The second column of these `rows` are `reference numbers` .
3. As you can see, there is an anchor on the second column. It opens a new tab.
4. On that new tab there are transactions, creating and updating of data.
5. Upon hitting the `save` button on that new tab, that tab will close (well, that's easy to do) but the catch here is, it will update the row with the new details on the calling `tab`

I have already a `update_row_details(personel_id)` function on the calling `tab`. So how will I call that `function` on the new `tab`? I'm sensing it's something like this:

My **main.html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Reference #</th>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-personel-id="081795">
            <th>1.</th>
            <td><a target="_blank" href="../query?id=081795">Gideon Apollo F. Bardelas</a></td>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
        <tr data-personel-id="091296">
            <th>2.</th>
            <td><a target="_blank" href="../query?id=091296">Karina Kal-la Athena F. Bardelas</a></td>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

on **callertab.js**

```
update_row_details(personel_id) {
    var row = $("tr[data-personel-id=" + row_index + "]");

    row.children()[1].text("blah, blah, blah");
    .
    .
    .
    row.children()[nth].text("blah, blah, blah");
}
```

on **newtab.js**

```
$("form#details").submit(function() {

    // Some ajax-saving

    // Insert your inter-tab function calling here, something like this:
    //
    // tab[1].update_row_details($("#personel_id").val());
    //
    // Then close this tab.

    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can access the caller page which is calling like

```
<a target="_blank" ...
```

Try the `window.open` method instead and then in a child window use [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) to update the state there. E.g.:

```
<a onclick="window.open('blablapage');event.preventDefault();" ...
```

JS on the main page:

```
function callMeFromChild(param1,param2){
    console.log(arguments)
}
```

JS on the child page:

```
function closeWindow(){
    // send params
    window.opener.callMeFromChild(123,"string")

    // close the window
    ...
}
```

Comment: But how can I pass some details from the `new tab` to the `calling tab`?

Comment: @Gideon added more samples